# Can there be a type constraint on a function's return type?

Tags: typescript

For example, how would you type a function that returns an array of objects that
are known to have at least one property of a specific type but the objects may or
may not also have other properties?

I tried the following type constraint:

```js
/**
* Return an array of elements that have property `a` of type `1`.
* The elements in the array may or may not also have other properties.
*/
function arrFunc<T extends { a: 1 }>(): T[] {
  return [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1 } ]
}
```

which doesn't work because for some reason `T` is allowed to be instantiated
with an arbitrary type unrelated to the constraint. Why is it allowed, i.e. why
does the type constraint not constrain the type?

I could make a generic type with a default type for a function to achieve the
desired typing, but it is not very nice since I can't in-line the type and the
function declaration, and I also have to write the constraint twice -- once for
the actual constraint and second time for the default value.

```js
type TFunc<A extends { a: 1 } = { a: 1 }> = () => A[];

const arrFunc: TFunc = () => {
    return [ { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2 } ];
}
```

Is it not possible to have a type constraint on a return value like you can on
arguments?

Comment: Why not just `: { a: 1 }[]`? And if you don't like the excess property checks, just assign to a variable and return that, but any other properties are _not_ accessible through the return interface. https://tsplay.dev/wXK8kW

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because your solution loses the exact information that the constraint attempts to preserve, i.e. the items in the returned array not being limited to having only that one property.

Answer (score 1):

There can, but it makes things difficult.

```
function arrFunc<T extends { a: 1 }>(): T[] { ... }
```

This is a perfectly valid function declaration with a perfectly valid type. But there can never be interesting values of that type. That's because the *caller* decides the generics. So when someone calls `arrFunc`, they pick a type `T` which extends `{a: 1}` and then it's the function's job to find an array of that specific `T`. That is, from inside the function, we have to work with *every* possible `T` we could ever encounter, not just the one we'd like to.

Now, "every possible `T`" in this case is every subtype of `{ a: 1 }`. That includes `{ a: 1 }` itself, it includes `{ a: 1, b: number }`, it includes `{ a: never }`, and (pathologically) it includes `never`. So if someone calls `arrFunc<never>`, our function needs to be prepared to handle that. And there aren't many lists whose elements are of type `never`. Specifically, there's one, and we call it `[]`, the empty list. So the valid implementations for your function are

```
// Return the only valid value
function arrFunc0<T extends { a: 1 }>(): T[] { return []; }

// Throw an exception
function arrFunc1<T extends { a: 1 }>(): T[] { throw "Oops!"; }

// Loop forever
function arrFunc2<T extends { a: 1 }>(): T[] { return arrFunc2<T>(); }

// Cast through any
function arrFunc3<T extends { a: 1 }>(): T[] { return "lol" as any as T[] }
```

The first is the only "legitimate" function, in the sense that all of the others either [bottom out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) or circumvent the type checker altogether.

Comment: Would it change the typing problem if the constraint was instead that property `a` was optional? Then the function's purpose could be e.g. to filter from an array those elements that have the property with the constrained value `1`. I fail to see why the function should consider all the subtypes when it can be implemented fully based on the constraint alone, i.e. by checking whether the property `a` exists and has the specified value.

Comment: Example of what I mean (apparently works when it's tied to a correspondingly typed argument!): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQMQK5mDAvDAPAFRgFMAPKIsAEwhgG94B+ALhgEYYBfAPgApEBzAIJIW+ANoBdAJSjJ2LnQCwAKBgwA9OpgIiUVAjDwEQpADoAZgEsANuQQ9DWBWDEByOK4nYsOVlIDcGloAtMHOIMRIIAgqajp6BjBidPAs7BwwXpowoQpEUTHKHCpAA -- Why does one of the return lines cause a type error while the other doesn't even though they both return values that satisfy the given constraint?

Comment: Because `arrFunc<never>([])` is a valid call and (if allowed) would produce a value of type `{ a: 1 }[]`, which is not a valid instance of `never[]`. In the `filter` case, it would produce a perfectly valid instance of `never[]`, namely `[]`.

Comment: So is the problem entirely based on the `never` type, i.e. the case where an array is empty? Could you still elaborate where the problem is if we don't consider arrays of any kind?

Comment: For example, why does one of the return lines in this example produce a type error while another doesn't even though they both return a value that satisfies the constraint: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAxArmYMC8MA8AVGAUwA8pCwATCGAbxgEMB+ALhgEYYBfAPgAp6ATgHNWeAJSiYAHxhgUAG3lZutALAAoGDACWcGP2EBtAOT1jAXSyZsbMTAGEoKAWFoNWHTgG4YAel8wALSBKoQCAiACGlq6+oJCJmaW1jZ2Dk4uDMI+-kEhsiBE4ZHRRPIQhPaOzq5yil4anBpAA

Comment: `never` is simply the best example of a `T` which extends your type that is difficult to instantiate. In your first example, `{ a: 1 }` is not an instance of `never`, a valid candidate for `T`. But it doesn't have to be `never`. It's *also* not an instance of `{ a: 1, b: number }`, which is another valid `T`. It's basically not a valid candidate for *any* `T` except specifically `{ a: 1 }`, and if you have a generic function that only works for one type, then it's not actually a generic function.

Comment: In the second example, you already have a `T` (for whatever `T` is), so it's safe to return it. We're depending on the type the user chose, but we are just giving them a value that they already told us is of the correct type.

Comment: We seem to agree on that `{ a: 1 }` is a valid `T`, and in fact as you pointed out, it's valid for exactly one subtype of `T`, hence not making it a useful generic function. But I still don't see why it's an error, even though I do see it's not useful as a generic function. As you said, `{ a: 1 }` is not valid for any `T` *except one*, but shouldn't one be just enough for it to compile?